# Android How to anchor two GridView Listener

Tags: android, gridview

in my activity i have 2 gridView. This gridView are in 2 different column. That i want to do is anchor the gridView so when i scroll( or click) in one of the two, the same happens in the other.

This is my xml layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.oldmount.fba.MyRoster">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/prova"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:text="SELEZIONA LA TUA ROSA!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@id/prova">

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/cardsGridView"
        android:numColumns="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxGridView"
        android:numColumns="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not combine your two GridView into one ListView and fill each row with a [`CheckedTextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html) which can take a drawable along with providing convenient checkbox.

Comment: can you write me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a `CheckedTextView` implementation for a simple app I wrote:

```
for (Game g : games) {
    final CheckedTextView ctv = new CheckedTextView(getActivity());

    String name = g.getName();
    String id = g.getValue();
    ctv.setText(name);

    fullGameMap.put(name, id);

    innerLayout.addView(ctv, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
    getActivity().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorMultiple, value, true);
    int checkMarkDrawableResId = value.resourceId;
    ctv.setCheckMarkDrawable(checkMarkDrawableResId);

    ctv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!ctv.isChecked()) {
                if (previousCheckedView != null)
                    previousCheckedView.setChecked(false);
                selectedGame = fullGameMap.get(ctv.getText().toString());
                ctv.setChecked(true);
                previousCheckedView = ctv;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This for loop populates a layout (that I have declared `innerLayout`) manually.  It simply iterates through a list to fill out the `CheckedTextView` with text and drawables.  Then it sets an `onClickListener` to handle the check box selection logic.

The concept would be the same in your case - instantiate a `CheckedTextView` and populate it with your assets, then add it to a layout, either manually like I did or ideally with a `ListView` + `BaseAdapter`.